# QGIS Relation ID Problem

Tags: qgis

I am currently testing the relation function of QGIS and I noticed that there can be some problems with IDs.
If you create a new feature in the parent layer but don't save it, this feature can be selected in the child layer, but the relation is deleted because the IDs are generated after saving.

I came across this question where "Damien" describes exactly this problem in a comment.

[Does QGIS attribute edit form support "relationship" data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83402/does-qgis-attribute-edit-form-support-relationship-data)

I have already tried the latest QGIS version, but the problem still exists.
I am using Geopackage as the data format.
My question on this would be if there is a better workaround than asking users to always save the parent features beforehand, as this can cause many problems if forgotten.

Comment: A possible solution would be to force the users to edit an unique key besides the ID, which is used to link layers, e.g. parcel codes.

Comment: Good idea, this solves the problem that relations disappear again after saving. However, it triggers some problems of its own, such as that users could reuse a deleted ID. Unfortunately it also doesn't solve the problem that a parent feature has to be created first.

Comment: As you describe it, it is more an issue of RDBMs rather than a QGIS issue. If you use a generated ID in a parent table, it is not possible to use that ID in a child table before it is generated which happens when the record is saved. If you use a manually set ID, you can insert record(s) in the child table at the same time as the record in the parent table is saved (or before, if you  do not have a constraint on the child table that disallows foreign keys that are not defined in the parent table)